# How would I ensure that the view is created after route params subscription has received values?

Tags: angular, routes, subscription

How would I make sure `View` is rendered after subscription has received values. On clicking `Edit` button in `MyComponent_1`, Angular routes to `MyComponent_2`. `MyComponent_2` view has a form whose values are required from route params subscription. How would I ensure that the view /form is created after params subscription has received values.

I have used 2 statements statement 1, statement 2. Which is better? or would you suggest any alternate approaches?

MyComponent_1.ts

```
  onEditRecipe() {
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route});
    // routes to MyComponent_2
  }
```

MyComponent_2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.id = +params['id'];

          this.formInit(); // form inti statement 1
          setTimeout(()=>{ alert("Hello"); this.formInit();}, 15000); // form inti statement 2
          
        }

      );
  }
 private formInit(){
     this.myform = new FormGroup(...//assigning form controls//..);
 }
```

MyComponent_2.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myform"> <!-- ... form controls ... --> </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

With Angular you can implement a Resolver. This class will be called when redirecting to some route and will run before the component be created. To use that, you will just create a new class that implements Resolve. Like the example above:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { SomeService } from 'src/app/service/Some.service.ts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ExampleResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private someService: SomeService,
    private router:Router,
  ){  }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    let id = route.params.id;
    return this.someService.getSomethingById(id);
  }

}
```

Then on your rounting module you just add a resolve property to your route object, just like data, component or path properties.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: MyComponentComponent,
    resolve: {something: ExampleResolve }
  },
  
];
```

Your component will be constructed after the resolver finish his job. The data provided by the resolver will than be added to "data" property of your route. To access that, you can subscribe to ActivatedRoute.data and get the info.

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
     something: Something;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataRelease = this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.something = data.something;
      })
      .add(() => {
        this.dataRelease.unsubscribe();
      });
  }
}
```

Than the data will be loaded before the view gets rendered. Hope that this will help you.